# What is exactly the meaning of "===" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs)

What's the diff between "===" and "==" ? Thanks!

Comment: Exact Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate of #359494.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

'===' means *equality without type coersion*. In other words, if using the triple equals, the values must be equal in type as well.

e.g.

```
0==false   // true
0===false  // false, because they are of a different type
1=="1"     // true, auto type coersion
1==="1"    // false, because they are of a different type
```

Source: http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html

Comment: its `type coercion` for those who are confusing about coersion.

Answer (score 16):

> Ripped from my blog: keithdonegan.com

**The Equality Operator (==)**

The equality operator (==) checks whether two operands are the same and returns true if they are the same and false if they are different.

**The Identity Operator (===)**

The identity operator checks whether two operands are “identical”.

These rules determine whether two values are identical:

- They have to have the same type.
- If number values have the same value they are identical, unless one or both are NaN.
- If string values have the same value they are identical, unless the strings differ in   length or content.
- If both values refer to the same object, array or function they are identical.
- If both values are null or undefined they are identical.

Answer (score 8):

The === operator means "is exactly equal to," matching by both value and data type.

The == operator means "is equal to," matching by value only.

Answer (score 3):

It tests exact equality of both value and type.

```
given the assignment
x = 7

x===7 is true
x==="7" is false
```

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell "===" tests for the equality of value AND of type:
[From here:](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.com/2007/09/triple-equals-in-javascript.html)