# Javascript Simple Boolean Arithemetic

Tags: javascript

I’ve heard of boolean arithmetic and thought of giving it a try.

```
alert (true+true===2)  //true
alert (true-true===0)  //true
```

So algebra tells me true=1

```
alert (true===1)  //false :O
```

Could someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is exactly the meaning of "===" in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029781/what-is-exactly-the-meaning-of-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`===` is the strict equality operator. Try `==` operator instead.
`true==1` will evaluate to `true`.

> The strict equality operator `===` only considers values equal if they
>   have the same type. The lenient equality operator `==` tries to
>   convert values of different types, before comparing like strict
>   equality.

**Case 1:**

In case of `true===1`, The data type of true is boolean whereas the type of 1 is number. Thus the expression `true===1` will evaluate to `false`.

**Case 2:**

In case of `true+true===2` and `true-true===0` the arithmetic operation is performed first(Since `+` operator takes precedence over `===`. [See Operator Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3ks45k7(v=vs.94).aspx)) and then the result is compared with the other operand.

While evaluating expression `(true+true===2)`, the arithmetic operation `true+true` performed first producing result 2. Then the result is compered with the other operand. i.e. `(2==2)` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @SOReadytoHelp Edited my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Because comparing data TYPE and value (that's what operator '===' does ), TRUE is not exactly the same as 1. If you changed this to TRUE == 1, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

first 2 expression are true because you are using expression `(true+true)` `(true-true)` it convert type of a value first due to expression and check equality with "===", `toNumber` and `toPrimitive` are internal methods which convert their arguments (during expression ) this is how conversion take place during expression

[image]

**That's why true+true equal to the 2**

In your third expression you are using **===** this not convert arguments just check equality with type, **to make it true both values and there type must be same**.

Thats all

Comment: sorry for that i was editing my answer that time, true+true is a expression, i have attached image to explain how boolean values convert during expression , have you  got idea how it was working ?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, you're doing bool + bool. The + operator takes precedence over the === operator so it's evaluated first. In this evaluation, it's converting the booleans to their number forms. Run `console.log(true + true);` and this will return 2. Since you're comparing the number 2 to the number 2, you get a return value true with the strict equality.

When you're just comparing `true === 1`, like everyone else said you're comparing the boolean true to the number 1 which is not strictly equal.