# why should we parse value in switch condition but not in if condition?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

```js
function runif() {
  let a = document.getElementById('test').value;
  if (a == 1) {
    console.log("works");
  }
}

function runswitch() {
  let a = document.getElementById('test').value;
  switch (a) {
    case 1:
      console.log("working");
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}

function runswitchOne() {
  let a = parseInt(document.getElementById('test').value);
  switch (a) {
    case 1:
      console.log("working");
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="test">
  <input type="button" onclick="runif()" value="click to check if">
  <input type="button" onclick="runswitch()" value="click to check without parseInt">
  <input type="button" onclick="runswitchOne()" value="click to check with parseInt">
</form>
```

This is the form I have created with a text input and two buttons.

In which the if statement recognize the input and does operation

But in switch I have to make it parse to recognize

I do not understand why it works? I know text input gives sting but if so how if() statement works without parsing?

normally we use if(a == "1") to compare string and not if(a==1)?

but even so it works

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison, your `if(a = 1)` does not actually test anything, it will always be fulfilled

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029781/what-is-exactly-the-meaning-of-in-javascript/1029792#1029792

Comment: Equality check `a == b` does, if types of a and b are different, *type coercion* (conversion) for you. Identity check `a === b` does also compare types and only returns true if both value and type match.

Comment: if ("one" == "one")  compares string and if ("one" == one ) throws error or not???

Comment: let even if 1 is considerd as "1" ;  will it compare as if ("1"==1) --> how will it be??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The switch ***case*** does the ***strict comparison*** (check both *value* and *type*).

The *value* of the element is of type string. Inside switch *case*  value is of type *int* and does not match. Thus without conversion, you code does not work.

But when use `a == 1` only the *value* are checked not the *type* and `"1" == 1` evaluates to *true*. If you do strict comparison (e.g., `===`), `"1" === 1` evaluates to *false* because in this case though the *value* is equal but the *type* is not equal.

The following will work:

```
switch (a) {
    case "1":
         .....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work without parsing, just change your expected value in the `switch` (`1`) to a string (`"1"`):

```
switch (a) {
    case "1":
        //Rest of code
}
```

Of course, in an `if` statement when you're using `==`, this does type conversion for you (`1 == "1"`). In a `switch`, it behaves like a `===` (equality operator, does not perform type coercion).

Comment: so you are saying that in an if statement when i am using ==, this does type conversion ! ..,yea, i tried it worked no body ever taut this i was thinking it just compares tqsm!

Comment: No problem @JacksonJegatheesan. Using `===` is also useful, because you learn when you're using different types in the wrong way.