# Discord.js: Can fetch a message by ID, but breaks when I replace the ID with a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to dynamically check for reactions on the message that was replied to, and it works fine when I paste the literal message id, but when I assign it to a variable, it gives a **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'users')**.

I used `msg.fetchReference()` to get the reference message, and it's assigned to `repliedTo`.  I've confirmed that `repliedTo.id` gives the id that worked when I pasted it in, and that the variable returns a string.

```
cacheChannel.messages.fetch(repliedTo.id).then(reactionMessage => {
    reactionMessage.reactions.resolve('').users.fetch().then(userList => {
        userList.map((user) => {
            if (user.id === 'testID') {
                console.log('already reacted');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Side note: I originally tried this without trying to fetch the message as it is now, and just using `repliedTo` instead of `reactionMessage`, but I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using `===` which also checks if `x1` and `x2` have the same data types! As you said, variable returns you a `String`, when `user.id` is a `Number`, so I'd recommend to try changing `===` to `==`, which only checks value! Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029781/what-is-exactly-the-meaning-of-in-javascript#:%7E:text=The%20%3D%3D%3D%20operator%20means%20%22is,%2C%22%20matching%20by%20value%20only.) is an explanation how it works!

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem. I think the issue occurs before it gets to the user.id part. I'm almost positive that it doesn't like something about using repliedTo.id instead of the id itself, which I was copying from the message in discord.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, when the ID mixed with letters it gives an error? You can use `isNaN function` to return it if the Id doesn't have any numbers or the id got mixed with letters.

```js
cacheChannel.messages.fetch(repliedTo.id).then(reactionMessage => {
    reactionMessage.reactions.resolve('').users.fetch().then(userList => {
        userList.map((user) => {
            if(isNaN(user.id)) {
                return message.reply("Your_Message")
            } else if (user.id === 'testID') {
                console.log('already reacted');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or you can use `try {} catch {}` function.

```js
cacheChannel.messages.fetch(repliedTo.id).then(reactionMessage => {
    reactionMessage.reactions.resolve('').users.fetch().then(userList => {
        userList.map((user) => {
            try {
              if (user.id === 'testID') {
                console.log('already reacted');
              }  
            } catch {
              return message.reply("Your_Message")
            } 
        });
    });
});
```